# Console telling me my element Id is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

Element Id is not defined for some reason and all the code looks fine.

```js
function qm() {
  var imgsiz = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1 
  console.log(imgsiz)
  if (imgsiz=="1"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=1.jpg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="2"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=2.jpeg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="3"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=3.jpg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="4"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=4.jpg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="5"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=5.jpg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="6"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=6.jpeg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="7"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=7.jpg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="8"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=8.jpg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="9"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=9.jpg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="10"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=10.jpg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="11"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=11.jpeg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="12"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=12.jpg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="13"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=13.jpg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="14"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=14.jpeg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="15"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=15.jpeg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="16"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=16.jpeg>"
  } else if (imgsiz=="17"){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src=1.jpg>"
  }
  var fonts = [ '1','2','1','2','3','4','5','6','5','6','7','8'];
  var font = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random()*fonts.length)];
  if (font=="1"){
    document.getElementById("quote")
    quote.style.fontFamily = "arial"
  } else if (font=="2"){
    document.getElementById("quote")
    quote.style.fontFamily = "tahoma"
  } else if (font=="3"){
    document.getElementById("quote")
    quote.style.fontFamily = "trebuchet"
  } else if (font=="4"){
    document.getElementById("quote")
    quote.style.fontFamily = "times new roman"
  } else if (font=="5"){
    document.getElementById("quote")
    quote.style.fontFamily = "georgia"
  } else if (font=="6"){
    document.getElementById("quote")
    quote.style.fontFamily = "garamond"
  } else if (font=="7"){
    document.getElementById("quote")
    quote.style.fontFamily = "courier new"
  } else if (font=="8"){
    document.getElementById("quote")
    quote.style.fontFamily = "brush script mt"
  }
  var rndoInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25 - 15)) + 15 
  console.log(rndoInt)
  document.getElementById("quote");
  quote.style.fontSize =  rndoInt + "px";
  var nouns = [' time ' , ' year ' , ' device ' , ' way ' , ' day ' , ' man ' , ' thing ' , ' woman ' , ' life ' , ' child ' , ' world ' , ' school ' , ' state ' , ' family ' , ' student ' , ' group ' , ' country ' , ' problem ' , ' hand ' , ' part ' , ' place ' , ' self ' , ' week ' , ' company ' , ' system ' , ' program ' , ' question ' , ' food ' , ' government ' , ' number ' , ' night ' , ' point ' , ' home ' , ' water ' , ' room ' , ' mother ' , ' area ' , ' money ' , ' story ' , ' bone ' , ' month ' , ' furniture ' , ' right ' , ' study ' , ' book ' , ' eye ' , ' job ' , ' word ' , ' business ' , ' issue ' , ' side ' , ' kind ' , ' head ' , ' house ' , ' service ' , ' friend ' , ' father ' , ' power ' , ' hour ' , ' game ' , ' line ' , ' clothing ' , ' member ' , ' law ' , ' car ' , ' city ' , ' community ' , ' name ' , ' president ' , ' team ' , ' minute ' , ' idea ' , ' kid ' , ' body ' , ' information ' , ' back ' , ' parent ' , ' face ' , ' innocent ' , ' level ' , ' office ' , ' door ' , ' health ' , ' person ' , ' life ' , ' war ' , ' history ' , ' party ' , ' dog ' , ' change ' , ' morning ' , ' partner ' , ' funeral ' , ' girl ' , ' guy ' , ' moment ' , ' air ' , ' teacher ' , ' force ' , ' educator' ];
  var noun = nouns[Math.floor(Math.random()*nouns.length)];
  var pnouns = [' times ' , ' years ' , ' devices ' , ' ways ' , ' days ' , ' men ' , ' things ' , ' women ' , ' lives ' , ' children ' , ' worlds ' , ' schools ' , ' states ' , ' families ' , ' students ' , ' groups ' , ' countries ' , ' problems ' , ' hands ' , ' parts ' , ' places ' , ' selves ' , ' weeks ' , ' companies ' , ' systems ' , ' programs ' , ' questions ' , ' food ' , ' governments ' , ' numbers ' , ' nights ' , ' points ' , ' homes ' , ' waters ' , ' rooms ' , ' mothers ' , ' areas ' , ' money ' , ' stories ' , ' bones ' , ' months ' , ' furniture ' , ' rights ' , ' studies ' , ' books ' , ' eyes ' , ' jobs ' , ' words ' , ' business ' , ' issues ' , ' sides ' , ' people ' , ' heads ' , ' houses ' , ' services ' , ' friends ' , ' fathers ' , ' powers ' , ' hours ' , ' games ' , ' lines ' , ' clothing ' , ' members ' , ' laws ' , ' cars ' , ' cities ' , ' communities ' , ' names ' , ' presidents ' , ' teams ' , ' minutes ' , ' ideas ' , ' kids ' , ' bodies ' , ' information ' , ' backs ' , ' parents ' , ' faces ' , ' innocents ' , ' levels ' , ' offices ' , ' doors ' , ' health ' , ' people ' , ' lives ' , ' wars ' , ' histories ' , ' parties ' , ' dogs ' , ' changes ' , ' mornings ' , ' partners ' , ' funerals ' , ' girls ' , ' guys ' , ' moments ' , ' airs ' , ' teachers ' , ' forces ' , ' educators ' ];
  var pnoun = pnouns[Math.floor(Math.random()*pnouns.length)];
  var adverbs = [' bashfully ' , ' beautifully ' , ' bitterly ' , ' bleakly ' , ' blindly ' , ' blissfully ' , ' boastfully ' , ' boldly ' , ' bravely ' , ' briefly ' , ' brightly ' , ' briskly ' , ' broadly ' , ' busily ' , ' calmly ' , ' carefully ' , ' carelessly ' , ' cautiously ' , ' certainly ' , ' cheerfully ' , ' clearly ' , ' cleverly ' , ' closely ' , ' coaxingly ' , ' colorfully ' , ' commonly ' , ' continually ' , ' coolly ' , ' correctly ' , ' courageously ' , ' crossly ' , ' cruelly ' , ' curiously ' , ' daily ' , ' daintily ' , ' dearly ' , ' deceivingly ' , ' deeply ' , ' defiantly ' , ' deliberately ' , ' delightfully ' , ' diligently ' , ' dimly ' , ' doubtfully ' , ' dreamily ' , ' easily ' , ' elegantly ' , ' energetically ' , ' enormously ' , ' enthusiastically ' , ' equally ' , ' especially ' , ' evenly ' , ' fortunately ' , ' frankly ' , ' frantically ' , ' freely ' , ' frenetically ' , ' hopelessly ' , ' shrilly ' , ' shyly ' , ' silently ' , ' sleepily ' , ' slowly ' , ' smoothly ' , ' publicly ' , ' solemnly ' , ' solidly ' , ' sometimes ' , ' rapidly ' , ' speedily ' , ' stealthily ' , ' sternly ' , ' strictly ' , ' unaccountably ' , ' unbearably ' , ' unethically ' , ' unexpectedly ' , ' unfortunately ' , ' unimpressively ' , ' unnaturally ' , ' unnecessarily ' , ' angrily ' , ' equally ' , ' blissfully ' , ' purposefully ' , ' vainly ' , ' valiantly ' , ' vastly ' , ' verbally ' , ' upsettingly ' , ' viciously ' , ' victoriously ' , ' violently ' , ' weakly ' , ' wearily ' , ' deppresingly ' , ' wetly ' , ' fully ' , ' wildly '];
  var adverb = adverbs[Math.floor(Math.random()*adverbs.length)];
  var verbs = [ ' be ' , ' keep ' , ' understand ' , ' shoot ' , ' beat ' , ' watch ' , ' do ' , ' begin ' , ' follow ' , ' say ' , ' devour ' , ' stop ' , ' abolish ' , ' help ' , ' create ' , ' suck ' , ' drown ' , ' speak ' , ' get ' , ' fight ' , ' read ' , ' choke ' , ' start ' , ' escape ' , ' make ' , ' trust ' , ' add ' , ' know ' , ' show ' , ' spend ' , ' steal ' , ' hear ' , ' grow ' , ' think ' , ' misuse ' , ' open ' , ' take ' , ' run ' , ' release ' , ' see ' , ' move ' , ' win ' , ' punch ' , ' like ' , ' offer ' , ' obliterate ' , ' live ' , ' remember ' , ' want ' , ' believe ' , ' love ' , ' steal ' , ' hold ' , ' consider ' , ' use ' , ' bring ' , ' find ' , ' break ' , ' accept ' , ' buy ' , ' give ' , ' rejoin ' , ' attend ' , ' tell ' , ' write ' , ' serve ' , ' work ' , ' provide ' , ' detonate ' , ' end ' , ' trust ' , ' deport ' , ' start ' , ' burn ' , ' expect ' , ' call ' , ' lose ' , ' build ' , ' try ' , ' pay ' , ' like ' , ' rob ' , ' meet ' , ' fail ' , ' need ' , ' include ' , ' cut ' , ' feel ' , ' sell ' , ' reach ' , ' become ' , ' blow ' , ' kill ' , ' leave ' , ' learn ' , ' ruin ' , ' bury ' , ' change ' , ' bully ' , ' lead '];
  var verb = verbs[Math.floor(Math.random()*verbs.length)];  
  var fronttexts = ['Always ','Never ','You only live once, ','Life is short ','Trust people that ','Dont trust people who ','Occasionally ','If you ever feel sad, ','If you are feeling up to it, ',''];
  var fronttext = fronttexts[Math.floor(Math.random()*fronttexts.length)];
  var adjectives = [' other ' , ' new ' , ' good ' , ' high ' , ' old ' , ' great ' , ' big ' , ' American ' , ' small ' , ' large ' , ' national ' , ' young ' , ' different ' , ' black ' , ' long ' , ' little ' , ' important ' , ' political ' , ' bad ' , ' white ' , ' real ' , ' best ' , ' right ' , ' senile ' , ' dead ' , ' public ' , ' sure ' , ' low ' , ' early ' , ' able ' , ' human ' , ' local ' , ' late ' , ' hard ' , ' major ' , ' better ' , ' economic ' , ' strong ' , ' possible ' , ' whole ' , ' free ' , ' military ' , ' true ' , ' federal ' , ' international ' , ' full ' , ' special ' , ' easy ' , ' clear ' , ' recent ' , ' certain ' , ' personal ' , ' open ' , ' red ' , ' difficult ' , ' available ' , ' likely ' , ' short ' , ' single ' , ' medical ' , ' current ' , ' wrong ' , ' private ' , ' past ' , ' foreign ' , ' fine ' , ' common ' , ' poor ' , ' natural ' , ' significant ' , ' similar ' , ' hot ' , ' dead ' , ' central ' , ' happy ' , ' serious ' , ' ready ' , ' simple ' , ' left ' , ' physical ' , ' general ' , ' environmental ' , ' financial ' , ' blue ' , ' democratic ' , ' dark ' , ' various ' , ' entire ' , ' close ' , ' legal ' , ' religious ' , ' cold ' , ' final ' , ' main ' , ' green ' , ' nice ' , ' huge ' , ' popular ' , ' traditional ' , '  cultural '];
  var adjective = adjectives[Math.floor(Math.random()*adjectives.length)];
  var presets = [ '1','2','1','2','3','4','5','6','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','11','12','13','14','15','16'];
  var preset = presets[Math.floor(Math.random()*presets.length)];
  if (preset == "1"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+verb+"your"+noun+"."
  } else if (preset == "2"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+verb+"a"+noun+"."
  } else if (preset == "3"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+adverb+verb+"your"+noun+"."
  } else if (preset == "4"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+adverb+verb+"a"+noun+"."
  } else if (preset == "5"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+verb+"your"+pnoun+"."
  } else if (preset == "6"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+verb+pnoun+"."
  } else if (preset == "7"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+adverb+verb+"your"+pnoun+"."
  } else if (preset == "8"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+adverb+verb+pnoun+"."
  } else if (preset == "9"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+verb+"your"+adjective+pnoun+"."
  } else if (preset == "10"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+verb+adjective+pnoun+"."
  } else if (preset == "11"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+verb+"your"+adjective+noun+"."
  } else if (preset == "12"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+verb+"a"+adjective+noun+"."
  } else if (preset == "13"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+adverb+verb+"your"+adjective+noun+"."
  } else if (preset == "14"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+adverb+verb+"a"+adjective+noun+"."
  } else if (preset == "15"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+adverb+verb+adjective+pnoun+"."
  } else if (preset == "16"){
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ""+fronttext+adverb+verb+"your"+adjective+pnoun+"."
  }
};
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
button {
    height : 100px;
    width : 100px;
    position : fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}  
img {
    width: 150px; 
    height: 150px; 
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 25% 25%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Inspirtaitonal quotesd genbaerator</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <div id="image">
    
  <p id="quote"></p>
  <button onclick="qm()">Make a quote</button>
</body>
  
</html>
```

I have image files in the replit, for those who are wondering what I am making, I amd creating a "inspirational" quote generator, its meant to be a funny strange quote generator. I have not yet added all of the images in (there are 100) so if that is the issue that would help but I dont beleive it is because the files are not used anywhere else.

Comment: Your script runs before the "image" `<div>` is added to the DOM. Also you forgot the closing tag on the `<div>`.

Answer (score -1):

### One reason for this happening could be that your script loads before the DOM has loaded

In which case you can either load the script after the dom loads

Note - Your div tag wasn't closed as well so I closed it here

```
<body>
  <div id="image"></div>
  <p id="quote"></p>
  <button onclick="qm()">Make a quote</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### Or

You can add the "defer" attribute to the script tag like

```
<head>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Your Code Here -->
</body>
```